# Google Maps API Key with file:// URLs

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Since the June 2018 billing changes do I need a Google Maps API key to develop local file-based HTML pages that use the Google Maps JavaScript API (the HTML files are opened directly in a web browser from the local disk so a typical URL would be "file:///c:/temp/test.html")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your URL is correct if you want to open a file from the local disk.

If you want to check if your path is correct, just drag and drop the local file into the browser: it'll automatically write the correct path.

Keep in mind that if you want to keep Maps free, you have to remain under a precise amount of requests for every service.

You can easily check your counters here:

[Google Maps API Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment but perhaps my question wasn't clear. I'm trying to understand if I need an API key (not whether the URL is correct).

Comment: Yes, you definitely need it.

You can get the api key going to the same dashboard i linked to you.

Then, you must include the key in the bottom part of your php like this



`<script
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=***YOUR KEY***&&libraries=places"></script>`